# A word for a business that makes supporting products for another, specific business?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language

Is there a business term for a company's whose products and services are entirely in support of another company's product or service? For example

- Companies that sell door fronts, door pulls and couch covers specifically for Ikea furniture.
- Repair companies that only repair one specific product or line of products.
- A software company that exclusively creates plug-ins for another company's software.

Sample sentence: "All our products are accessories for Playosityᵀᴹ dolls because we are a ___ company."

Comment: Presumably, these businesses are not direct subsiduaries of the company whose products/services they support?

Comment: @KillingTime I suppose they could be. A word that includes both subsidiary companies and independent companies would be fine.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I edited my question.

Comment: The Q is a little broad...does OEM work?

Comment: It's just a sub-contractor.

Comment: @Lambie A company that sells iPhone cases has no contract whatsoever with Apple - they're certainly not a sub-contractor.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The question states: All our products are accessories for Playosityᵀᴹ dolls. The **most likely relationship** here is sub-contracting. Not all manufacturers make their own "accessories".

Answer (score 1):

**Supplier** is the usual term in business.

[Cambridge Business Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supplier) defines *supplier*:

> a company that provides a product, or the materials to make a product:
>
> - supplier of sth to sb/sth The company is a supplier of software to the film industry.
> - leading/main/key supplier They used to be a leading supplier of medical equipment.
> - Most energy suppliers are doing well in the current economic climate.

For examples the UK government Department for Business & Trade has a [website](https://www.great.gov.uk/international/trade/) which promises to help foreign businesses "Find a UK supplier" "Our digital service helps you find UK suppliers of products and services across industries". Business information site Business Gateway offers [advice](https://www.bgateway.com/resources/choosing-and-managing-suppliers) on "Choosing and managing suppliers".

Together the network of suppliers and distributors forms a [supply chain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/supply-chain).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be the abbreviation **B2B** (for business-to-business). Nowadays one could say:

> Acme Inc doesn't sell to the public as they are in the B2B space.

P.S. B2B, though it would be well-known to anyone who does purchasing on the internet for a business, might not be known to a general audience. The full form *business-to-business* would be better for the latter audience.

Comment: @jsw29: Not sure what you meant by your prescriptive comment "should be reserved for B2B communications".  That "B2B" should only be used by such businesses in their own communications?

Comment: Point taken. I'll add that its ubiquity on the internet shouldn't be confused with it being a "mainstream" abbreviation like TLC or LMAO.

Answer (score 0):

“Picks and Shovels" is the term.

Here are some links to definitions and usages:

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/picks-and-shovels

https://www.forbes.com/sites/robtoews/2020/03/22/a-massive-opportunity-exists-to-build-picks-and-shovels-for-machine-learning/?sh=973d297ab347

Comment: Please don't simply give links. Provide the reasoning **in  your answer** (and correctly cited) linking to corroborative evidence off-site.

Answer (score 0):

"**Auxiliary company**" might work:

> An auxiliary company refers to a subsidiary or affiliated company that is established with the primary purpose of providing assistance and support to the main company in its day-to-day operations and functions.
> [[S]pecialized or complementary activities] could include providing essential services, manufacturing components, supplying goods, or offering technical expertise [..]
> <sup>[source](https://www.fisdom.com/glossary/auxiliary-company/)</sup>

Even though this might not be a common term, the word '[auxiliary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/auxiliary)' will probably suffice to get your point across—either as an adjective to 'company' or as a standalone noun:

> adj.
>
> - additional; supplementary; reserve
>
> noun
>
> - an organization allied with, but subsidiary to, a main body of restricted membership, especially one composed of members' relatives

Answer (score 0):

If the focus is on direct involvement with one company only, as your sample sentence implies:

> All our products are accessories for Playosityᵀᴹ dolls because we are a ___ company."

you could use the phrase **[captive distributor](https://www.ventureline.com/accounting-glossary/C/captive-distributor-definition/)**.

> We don't sell to the public as we are a captive distributor for Playosityᵀᴹ and all our products are accessories for their products.